# Smarty modulus?

Tags: php, smarty

I'm in a loop to display products...

4 per row, unlimited rows'

I need to know if it's the nth entry... example every 4 items... So I know its the first column as in 
item 1, item5, item 9 etc... 
Or last item 
item 4, item 8, item 12

Tried these where

```
{foreach from=$sproducts item="product" name="sproducts"}
{counter assign="bobis" name="bobis"  }

{if $bobis is  div by 4|| $laster ==1}
{if $bobis mod 4 == 0}

 {if $bobis !=4 && $bobis !=8 && $bobis != 12}
```

Any simple way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand the question right, just put a `col-` class on your item:

```
<div class="col-{$bobis mod 4}">...</div>
```

You should get the following:

```
<div class="col-1">...</div>
<div class="col-2">...</div>
<div class="col-3">...</div>
<div class="col-4">...</div>
<div class="col-1">...</div>
<div class="col-2">...</div>
```

...and so on

Answer (score 1):

If you are using tables this is something I pulled from a script I am currently working on and adapted to your code somewhat.  You probably would have to make some changes but it somewhat gives you an idea.

```
<table>
{foreach from=$sproducts item="product" name="sproducts"}
{if $product@first}<tr>{/if}
<td>{$product}</td>
{if $product@last}</tr>
{else}{if $product@iteration is div by 4}</tr><tr>
{/if}
{/if}
{/foreach}
</table>
```